# Override @timestamp to get correct correct %{+yyyy.MM.dd} in index name

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I'm let Filebeat reading line-by-line json files, in each json event, I already have `timestamp` field (format: 2021-03-02T04:08:35.241632)

After processing, there is a new field `@timestamp` (might meta field Filebeat added, equals to current time), and seems index pattern `%{+yyyy.MM.dd}` (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/elasticsearch-output.html#index-option-es) was configured to that field. I want to override `@timestamp` with timestamp processor: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/processor-timestamp.html but not work, might be the layout was not set correctly?

```
- timestamp:
      field: timestamp
      layouts:
        - '2021-03-02T03:29:29.787331'
```

```
2021-03-07T11:29:39.382+0700    DEBUG   [processor.timestamp]   timestamp/timestamp.go:173  Failure parsing time field. {"error": "failed parsing time field timestamp='2021-03-02T03:29:29.787331'", "errorCauses": [{"error": "failed using layout [2021-03-02T03:29:29.787331] cannot parse [-03-02T03:29:29.787331] as [1]"}]}
```

I also tried another approach to parse timestamp using `Date.parse` but not work, not sure if ECMA 5.1 implemented in Filebeat missing something:

```js
var date = new Date.parse('2021-03-02T03:29:29.787331');
    event.Put('@metadata.index_suffix', date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate());
```

```
  "error": {
    "message": "TypeError: Not a constructor at process (/Users/thoong/Projects/shodan/shodan-trends/transform.js:25:16(106))"
  },
```

So with my `timestamp` format is `2021-03-02T03:29:29.787331`, I want to ask what is the correct `layouts` for the processor or to parse with `Date.parse`?

#### Solution, here is the correct layouts from @Val answer

```
- timestamp:
      field: timestamp
      layouts:
        - '2006-01-02T15:04:05.000000'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify the `layouts` parameter if your `timestamp` field already has the ISO8601 format.

However, if your `timestamp` field has a different layout, you must specify a very specific reference date inside the layout section, which is `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006` and you can also provide a `test` date. ([more info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/processor-timestamp.html))

So in your case it would be:

```
- timestamp:
    field: timestamp
    ignore_missing: true
    ignore_failure: true
    layouts:
      - '2006-01-02T15:04:05.000000'
    test:
      - '2021-03-02T03:29:29.787331'
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried your layout but it didn't work, @timestamp still mapping to the current time

Comment: ahh, this format worked: 2006-01-02T15:04:05.000000, remove -07:00